# Neural Prophet: n_lags and n_historic_predictions Possible Issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, facebook-prophet

I want to train a Neural Prophet model based on some data for number of people entering stores in the time frame of January 1, 2022 to May 30, 2023. The original data has a lot of spikes (See first image, solid lines)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hf35.png)

The dashed lines show what the Neural Prophet model creates based on the following hyper parameters:

```
model = NeuralProphet(
            growth="off",  # Determine trend types: 'linear', 'discontinuous', 'off'
            changepoints=0, # list of dates that may include change points (None -> automatic )
            n_changepoints=0,
            changepoints_range=0.8,
            trend_reg=0,
            trend_reg_threshold=False,
            seasonality_reg=0.1,
            d_hidden = 0,
            n_lags=30,
            num_hidden_layers=0,     # Dimension of hidden layers of AR-Net
            ar_reg=None,  # Sparcity in the AR coefficients
            learning_rate=0.01,
            epochs=100,
            normalize="auto",  # Type of normalization ('minmax', 'standardize', 'soft', 'off')
            impute_missing=True,        
            yearly_seasonality='auto',
            weekly_seasonality='auto',
            daily_seasonality= 'auto',
            seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
            loss_func="MSE",
        )

model.fit(data,freq="D")  
future = model.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=1000,n_historic_predictions=len(data))
forecast = model.predict(future)
```

Now the issue is, when I include n_lags and n_historic_predictions, the predictions that neural prophet gives me is not in the future, but rather the same time as what the original dataframe covers. I tried removing n_historic_predictions, but then the predictions dont become accurate. I would like for my Neural Prophet model to predict in a pattern similar to what the original data has. But it seems that its not predicting for future values.

FYI. I used this as a reference. They use n_lags and n_historic_predictions as well in their example, but it doesn't seem to work for mine.

https://github.com/e-alizadeh/data-science-blog/blob/master/notebooks/NeuralProphet/neural_prophet.ipynb

I tried removing n_historic_predictions, n_lags, tweaking other parameters. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try including 'n_forecasts' in your model params.

For example: if you want to predict 7 timesteps in the future, then the model object should have n_forecasts=7. Now, create a future dataframe with 7 timesteps in the future.

```
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet, set_random_seed
set_random_seed(0) # For consistent results

model = NeuralProphet(**params, n_forecasts=7)
model_forecast = model.predict(future_df)
```

Even with a future dataframe of 100 timesteps, the model will only predict based on n_forecasts.

Comment: I'm curious why it is called `n_forecasts` instead of horizon.

Comment: `n_forecasts` is the hyperparameter. Horizon is the pesudo variable name. They both go hand in hand in the neural prophet paper

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  How can a forecasting horizon be a hyperparamter?  This isn't something you would tune but something that is determined by how far into the future you need to predict.